# Failing test in ruby tutorial (Michael Hartl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm studying Michael Hartl's tutorial. I'm using RSPEC to run the test.
So far so good but it seems that I've hit the wall with the following example.

Here is the test that fails (it should pass):

```
describe "authenticate method" do
  it "should return the user on email/password match" do
    matching_user = User.authenticate(@attr[:email], @attr[:password])
    matching_user.should == @user
  end
end
```

Just in case.
***@user defined as:***

```
before(:each) do
  @user = User.create!(@attr)
end
```

***@attr defined as:***

```
before(:each) do        
  @attr = {
          :name => "Example user", 
          :email => "user@example.com",
          :password => "foobar",
          :password_confirmation => "foobar"
        }
end
```

***Entries in user.rb***

```
before_save :encrypt_password

def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end

def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil  if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
end

private

def encrypt_password 
      self.salt = make_salt unless has_password?(password)
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password) 
end

def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
end

def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
end

def secure_hash(string)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
end
```

***Error message displayed when the test is failing***

```
c:\RailsInstaller\work\apptwit>rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
.................F

Failures:

  1) User password validations password encryption authenticate method should return the user on email/password
     Failure/Error: matching_user.should == @user
       expected: #<User id: 1, name: "Example user", email: "user@example.com", created_at: "2011-12-07 19:08:23
ed_at: "2011-12-07 19:08:23", encrypted_password: "fbdbaf712fa1b6c925c4ab2192e73ac9f9d1bedf67630610d68...">
            got: nil (using ==)
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:204:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 221.37 seconds
18 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:202 # User password validations password encryption authenticate method should
he user on email/password match
```

I would appreciate any pointers,
Thanks a lot.

Comment: is there any way I can add points for the comments? (new to this site)

Comment: No, but I can add it as an answer if it helped solve your problem and then you can. I'm curious as to what was happening and what fixed it

Comment: it is not fixed, but I find the ideas useful - I'm learning RoR using Hart tutorial

Comment: I think it may be related to the fact the I use salt to encrypt user passwords and salt is always nil when new user is created:
***
#<User id: 15, name: "John Doe", email: "jdoe@ibm.com", created_at: "2011-12-10 04:00:35", updated_at: "2011-12-
:35", encrypted_password: "07fe1b78a05a2657b228745a957a3d1cc2c45597b74099a3d7b...", salt: nil>

Comment: Yeah you should definitely be making a salt.... You may want to do `self.salt = make_salt if new_record?` instead so it makes it for every new user

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear from the answer - the fact that every user is created with nil salt parameter (even though the config for salt is present) - can lead to " matching_user.should == @user, got: nil (using ==) " error?

Comment: No, but it can make your password be incorrect since `has_password?` encrypts the string you pass in to check if your encrypted password field matches whatever you passed in to `has_password?`.  If you salt starts off as nil and then later gets a value, `has_password?` will return false.  Also, having a nil salt is just insecure so either way it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I posted it as a separate topic, if you have any ideas...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458489/salt-field-is-nil-for-all-users

Comment: ok, I've figured it out. I had a line in users.rb "attr_accessor :password, :salt" which basically makes :salt a virtual attribute. But there is a corresponding column in the db that actually stores salt hash. (I had to add salt to this line as advised in the other post in SO, but I shouldn't have). Once you remove :salt from attr_accessor :password, :salt then everything starts working.

Comment: Good catch!  Looks like you learned about virtual attributes the hard way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `matching_user` is nil, then you might want to put some `puts email` and `puts user.inspect` statements in `self.authenticate` to debug it.

It seems as though it's either not able to find the user by email or your password is incorrect for some reason in the authenticate method.