# Salt field is nil for all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

(ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.1) Following Michael Hartl's tutorial. Spent more than a day trying to figure out the issue, re-read the chapter, browsed SO, no solution so far.
When I create users they are all created with nil in salt field in DB. Like that:

```
=> #<User id: 19, name: "John Doe Fourth", email: "jdoe4@ibm.com", created_at: "2011-12-10 16:36:09", updated_at: "2011-
12-10 16:36:09", encrypted_password: "5534438b422e928e80479756608b87d33881b5196a28be230c2...", salt: nil>
```

This (imho) the reason I get "invalid user/email combination" when I try to login.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Here is the info that you might need, hope it's not too much.

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
            sign_in @user
            flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Blue Bird Microblog!"
            redirect_to @user
      else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
require 'digest' class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
attr_accessor :password, :salt

 before_save :encrypt_password

 def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)   
 end

 def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
     user = find_by_email(email)
     puts user.inspect
     return nil  if user.nil?
     return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)   
 end

  def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
     user = find_by_id(id)
     (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil   
  end

 private

 def encrypt_password 
       self.salt = make_salt unless has_password?(password)
       self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password) 
     end

  def encrypt(string)
       secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
     end

     def make_salt
       secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
     end

     def secure_hash(string)
       Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
     end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove

```
attr_accessor :salt
```

attr_accessor is for instance variables, and since salt is in the database; you need to get rid of that accessor line for it.

Comment: Damn :)
I figured it out myself and wanted to share it with everybody, but here comes your answer :)
I actually went through a long comparison between my files and M. Hartl's files posted on github. Then I figured out what was going on. Unlike you I couldn't figure it out just by looking at the code. I really appreciate your answer though, thanks a lot.